# System.IO.FileInfo is not showing in Drop down completion list in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop

I am writing this class

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Comparison.Strategies; // this namespace contains the ICompare interface

namespace Comparison{

    public class FileNameCompare : ICompare
    {   
        public bool compare(FileInfo a, FileInfo b)
        {
            a. 
        //   ^
        //   Pressing . does not show FileInfo properties or methods (!!)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is  when I press `.` (see the code comments above) it does not product completion list. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> It show a completion list but that does not show any properties of `FileInfo` class.

- My target platform is setup as `Mono/.NET 2.0`in the project option.
- I have also implemented same Interface in other project where completion list is show properly.
- If I just add a `return true` the code compiles!

So could anyone tell me **why**  the `.` is not triggering completion list of `FileInfo` class? and **How** could I **fix it**?

**Update:**

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> after writing `System.IO.`, in the completion list I see this,

[image]

Comment: Could it be because you're missing a semicolon after `using Comparison.Strategies`? Also, your `ICompare` interface seems identical to the `IComparer<FileInfo>` interface that's included in .NET, so you might want to consider using that.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek thats a typo. In fact my code compiles if I just add `return true` in the `compare` method. :)

Comment: @AllonGuralnek Also pressing Ctrl+Space after writing `System.IO.Fi` does not show `FileInfo` in the list!

Comment: What classes are shown after typing `System.IO.`?

Comment: @AllonGuralnek I have update the question with that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the code completion and refactoring engine in MonoDevelop <= 2.8 is not ideal and is currently being reworked to one using [NRefactory](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory). You can try the new engine by using the newest MD beta or compiling it from git sources. Nevertheless you most likely want to wait until it stabilize.

Comment: I just noticed its happening when I am creating a class library and extending and interface from different namespace.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: The issues are here and there, but IMO there is no much point in issuing a bug unless you're using the new resolver already. The new engine probably arrives to MD soon, so you just need to wait for the better ;)